# Reading Notification center's notifications

Tags: ios, notifications

Is it possible to read all notifications received in the iPhone, during the app launch. If we launch the app through notification we get info through launchOptions. Is it any way I can access notification center and read all notifications during the app launch.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396630/xcode-why-launchoptions-in-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-always-nil