# kill a app in switcher, then launch it from a local notification, launchOptions is nil in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, null, launch

App get a local notification when it's in background, and then I killed it in switcher. When I tap the notification, the app relaunched with the launchOptions values nil,so I can't get any information about the local notification,what should I do? And more, if I get more than one local notification, how do I distinguish which notification I tapped? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

launchOptions values nil is due to that relaunching the app with XCode (in this case with the "Waiting for my MyApp to launch" option in Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme) deletes the notifications even if it is still displayed in the status bar, so just instead showing values in an alertView
detail:[XCode : why launchOptions in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions always nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396630/xcode-why-launchoptions-in-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-always-nil)